# OSB alert configuration - 11g

Tags: oracle, soa, osb

Please help me out in solving configuring alert with email as a destination. I have configured SMTP server and tested through Business service receiving mail properly but when used same SMTP server for alert destination to notify by email not receiving any mail neither any error. Suggest me

Comment: well we need code , examples , something to understand whats going on in order to help you. your question is too broad.

Comment: Can you please include more specific details? Configurations, error messages, logs etc?

Comment: My Straight forward question is SMTP server which is working when used in BS but when used same in Alert destination for email not working even though i have configured the alert destination and also alert rule in PS like if message count is = 0 then send mail alert with aggregation interval 10 min.

Comment: Enabled monitoring in operational setting, Added Mail Recipients - user@gmail.com ,selected SMTP server.  i have another query like in some blog its mentioned that Mail Recipients format should be mailto:user@gmail.com but when i tried to write mailto:user@gmail.com then its not allowing me to save error populating Mail Recipients is invalid. So am using format Mail Recipients user@gmail.com. suggest me is any configuration i have missed to do.

Comment: Is there any logging in the server logs about it? Could you share your alert destination?

Comment: NAme : SLAalertDestination , SNMP trap yes, Logging yes and Reporting no , Email recipients username@gmail.com , selected SMTP server and from name and address mentioned gmail id.

Comment: Is no one has an idea on this , i have also searched in google not an proper answer got now facing issue like below - It will be a great help if anybody help me.

Comment: I tried now with pipleline alert to send mail but getting error even

Comment: <Oct 28, 2018 9:42:28 PM IST> <Error> <ALSB Alert Rule Engine> <BEA-394004> <Failed to invoke action email that is part of alert destination AlertDestination Queue_Demo/proxyservices/HelloWorldAlertForPipeline. Resource: ProxyService Queue_Demo/proxyservices/Alert_PS. Alert Rule Name: N/A.
com.bea.wli.sb.transports.TransportException
 at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.email.EmailOutboundMessageContext.send(EmailOutboundMessageContext.java:81)
 at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.email.EmailTransportProvider.sendMessageAsync(EmailTransportProvider.java:152)

Comment: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.email.util.EmailUtil.send(EmailUtil.java:288)
 at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.email.EmailOutboundMessageContext.send(EmailOutboundMessageContext.java:69)
 at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.email.EmailTransportProvider.sendMessageAsync(EmailTransportProvider.java:152)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)